# C# & Mongo Net structuring database connection

Tags: c#

Not sure how I should say this, but I want to make my code cleaner and simpler.

Right now I have to make a new Connection for every method:

```
public static bool CheckUser(ulong userid)
{
        var client = new MongoClient("");
        var db = client.GetDatabase("Aureliadb");
        var collection = db.GetCollection<User>("user");
        var check = collection.Find(x => x.id == userid).ToList();;

        if (check.Count == 0) 
            return false;
        else 
            return true;
```

But I would like to have something like a static connection so I can access the database wherever I want. I tried something like this:

```
    public static dynamic AureliaDB(string selectedCollection)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient("");
        var db = client.GetDatabase("Aureliadb");
        var collection = db.GetCollection<User>(selectedCollection);
        return collection;
    }
```

Here I get a collection back that I selected. That didn't work with the `collection.Find()` so, my question is: how do I avoid writing the same code over and over again?

PS: I am quite new to C# and coding...

Here is my solution:

```cs
        static IMongoClient client = new MongoClient("");
        static IMongoDatabase db = client.GetDatabase("Aureliadb");
        static IMongoCollection<User> userCollection = db.GetCollection<User>("user");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am dumb. For everybody who might be braindead for a sec:

Just declare at the top of your file/class and everyone is gucci. ;o

Comment: Hey mate, well done finding your answer all by yourself. It would be awesome if you could share a snippet of code in your answer for future reader. Also no need to call yourself braindead doing mistake is part of our journey. Cheers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ye. That's true. Thanks! And I edited my question. Somehow I wasn't able to edit my own answer...